# Write different Unicode characters while CapsLock is active, by pressing key combination

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to rewrite my formerly hotkey script to bash, so I can use it on Linux.

I am trying to do infinite while loop which check whether CapsLock is active or not.
If it is, the same key combination produces uppercase letter, if it is not, it produces the same letter, but lowercase.

```
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
read -n 1 a

if [[ 'CapsLock is active' ]]
then
  case $a in
    \033A*)     echo -e '\u00C5';; # Å  
    \033E*)     echo -e '\u00C6';; # Æ  
    \033O*)     echo -e '\u00D8';; # Ø  
    \033U*)     echo -e '\u016E';; # Ů  
   esac
else
  case $a in    
    \033a*)     echo -e '\u00E5';; # å  
    \033e*)     echo -e '\u00E6';; # æ  
    \033o*)     echo -e '\u00F8';; # ø  
    \033u*)     echo -e '\u016F';; # ů
   esac
fi
done
```

I have two problems:

1. I don´t know how to write "when CapsLock is active, do this..."
2. How to write individual cases for each key combination (while pressing Alt+A (CapsLock active), write Å in text files, Alt+a -  write å, etc.)

And before you ask, yes, I did check if similar question/s has been posted and tried to find answers by myself. This is as far as I got.

Comment: I have a silly question for you: why don't you just use US ALTGR-INTL? I've redefined my CPSLK to be the "compose" key, which allows me to type things like Æ æ ø Ø Å å č ñ  using combinations like (cps+A E => Æ) (cps+/ O => Ø) (cps+~ n) and so forth ... it's actually less typing than unicode sequences.

Comment: Shell knows nothing about CapsLock and symbol translation. In virtual console you can read state e.g. with `kbdinfo gkbled` but it will not work under X. Moreover, usually Shift inverts effect of CapsLock for letters but doesn't for digits. Do you want to implement your own keyboard layout from scratch in bash? You can switch keyboard to scancode or keycode mode by `kbd_mode` and handle all key presses. Or just configure appropriate keyboard layout. What is the goal of your script?

Comment: Why trying to do it just for shell, and not for the whole window manager?

Comment: @dimich - the point of my script is to bind certain key combinations (Ctrl+a, or example) with a given unicode symbols (å), so I can write them in any text file (like you would write in notepad, word, etc.), WITHOUT installing Norwegian or any other additional keyboard. Moreover, the same key combination should produce different result (lowercase or uppercase of the same letter symbol) based on whether CapsLock is active or not. That is all.

Comment: @user1934428 - I don't know, maybe doing it for whole window manager is correct; maybe I shouldn't use bash at all for this kind of script (writing) / this is the first time I am trying to do anything with it at all.

If it can be done with it though, then I would like to us it.

Comment: @Blu3Rat You can't read `Ctrl+a` etc in non-raw mode because such combinations are handled by terminal driver before putting chars to stdin. You can read `Alt+a` but `\033` is separate char for `read` and you should handle it separately. But you can't distinguish `Alt+a` from sequential `Esc` then `a`. A key with `Alt` is already translated to ASCII according to CapsLock and Shift state, so you don't need to know CapsLock state. E.g. `Alt+a` without CapsLock produces `0x1b, 0x61`, with CapsLock it is `0x1b, 0x41`. Moreover, most of console editors won't work with piped stdin, they require tty.

Comment: @Blu3Rat In X you can configure XCompose. It allows to bind any character sequence to compose key + almost any key sequence.